# Term for initial condition defined as a surface

Tags: partial-differential-equations, reference-request

I am analyzing the following PDE $$P\frac{\partial^2P}{\partial x\partial y}=\frac{\partial P}{\partial x}\frac{\partial P}{\partial y}$$Which is a second order non-linear partial differential equation. The "initial condition" for $P$ is $P(a-1,a)=1$ for all real $a$. My question is the term for the initial condition, because there is an infinite amount, and it looks more like a surface that the function must be on. Is there a term for this initial condition then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This condition is usually referred as 'initial curve'.

These 'infinite amount' of initial conditions form a curve in $\mathbb{R}^3$ (not a surface) that must be contained in the graph of the solution.

This is usually the type of initial conditions given for PDE with two variables. More generally, for PDE with $n$ variables, one should have a condition as a hyperspace of dimension $n-1$.

For ODE (PDE of a single variable) the hyperspace is just a point.

Comment: Okay, thank you for your answer. It was actually a line after graphing it.